# how to get the place details from place ID in android(kotlin)

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

Hi i want to get place details with placeID and add marker in android maps activity using kotlin. i have done it with latlng but am not getting with placeID . can any pleease help.
my code with latlng .

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        val mdis= LatLng(1.301440, 103.847980)

        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(mdis).title("MDIS").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mdis))
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn())
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15F),2000,null)
        mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled=true
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        }
        else {//condition for Marshmello and above
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION)
            }
        }
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
    }
```

Tried this and am getting error at  placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener(response) ->{
Error says Type mismatch Required: OnSuccessListener
                         found : FetchplaceResponse

This is my updated code :

```
 override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        var mdisplaceId = "ChIJRwCirzca2jERhd68E52R_2Q"
        //val placesClient = Places.createClient(this)

        var placeFields : List<Place.Field>
        placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID , Place.Field.NAME)

       var  request :  FetchPlaceRequest
        request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(mdisplaceId, placeFields)

        lateinit var response : FetchPlaceResponse
        lateinit var placesClient : PlacesClient
            placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener(response) ->{  //error at this line near response 
            var place : Place
             place = response.getPlace()
        })
    }
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place

Comment: Or this one: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-id#place-details

Comment: Tried the second link // Define a Place ID.
String placeId = "INSERT_PLACE_ID_HERE";

// Specify the fields to return.
List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);

// Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, placeFields);

placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
  
}).  Tried this am getting error in this line of code
  placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) ->

Comment: Can you edit your question and put this code into it?

Comment: @ChintanSoni Done edit Please check

Answer (score 0):

Use Geocoding api,

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway,%20Mountain%20View,%20CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY)

which will return the following json response,

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "277",
           "short_name" : "277",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Bedford Avenue",
           "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
           "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kings County",
           "short_name" : "Kings County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "11211",
           "short_name" : "11211",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "277 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.7142205,
           "lng" : -73.9612903
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.71556948029149,
              "lng" : -73.95994131970849
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.7128715197085,
              "lng" : -73.9626392802915
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

Get the lat long from geometry object and add marker on the google maps.

Comment: am getting this as result  {
   "error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: follow this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start